# How do I load XMLTYPE from file?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have big (1 Mb +) XML file that is stored in local folder (for example: c:\temp\data.xml) that should be loaded inside XMLTYPE variable

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

the size limit of an Oracle XMLTYPE field should be 4 GB so you will not experience problems loading files having size of 1 MB.
You have to create on Oracle directory (on the Database server), put into the created directory your xml file, then execute your insert as follow:

```
oracle@server>mkdir yourdirectory
oracle@server>chown youroracleaccount.youroraclegroup yourdirectory
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY XMLDIR AS 'YOURDESIREDPATH'
SQL> GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY XMLDIR TO <DESIREDORACLESCHEMA>
SQL> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE VALUES (...., XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'yourfilename.xml') , nls_charset_id('YOURCHARSETID') ));
SQL> commit;
```

If you want to put your xml in a variable, you have to create an external table, for example as follow (but you can adjust this sample as you neeed):

```
CREATE TABLE YOURXMLTABLE (doc CLOB)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY xmlfile_dir
ACCESS PARAMETERS
(
FIELDS (lobfn CHAR TERMINATED BY ',')
COLUMN TRANSFORMS (doc FROM lobfile (lobfn))
)
LOCATION ('yourfilename.xml')
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

and then execute

```
select * into XMLTYPVARIABLE from XMLTABLE
```

Regards
Giova

Comment: I tried to execute code you provided with create table inside pl/sql developer - it has some syntax errors.

Comment: The directory has to be on the DB server and read/writable by the Oracle operating system account. It can't be on the client machine, if that's what the OP meant by 'local folder'. And `XMLTABLE` is a function name so using that as the name of your external table is going to be confusing at best, if it works at all.